# Invoking method of anonymous class

Tags: java, class, methods, anonymous-class

Java 7

First of all, I'm going to simplify the example to avoid posting unnecesary code. My specific concrete example a little bit complicated, but I' try to preserve the point.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test t = new Test(){ //<---------------------------------------------------------
            public void m(){ //                                                         |
                Test t = new Test(){//                                                  |
                    public void m(){//                                                  |
                        //Here I need to invoke the most inclosing class's m() method 
                    }
                    //other actions
                };
            }

            public void someMethod(){
                //action
            }
        };
    }

    public void m(){

    }
}
```

Is it possible to do in Java? I mean, to invoke the method of anonymous class that way?

Comment: What method you want to call exactly?

Comment: @sp00m `m()` of the anonymous class.

Answer (score 3):

No **it's impossible** because there is no reference to the anonymous classes.

This is the only possible way to call the instance `m()` method :

```
new Test(){                                                
   public void m(){                                                

   }  
}.m();
```

By definition according to the oracle documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) :

> Anonymous classes enable you to make your code more concise. They
>   enable you to declare and instantiate a class at the same time. They
>   are like local classes except that they do not have a name. Use them
>   if you need to use a local class **only once**

**So if you have to use one of the methods of your class you have to create a local one**.

Comment: `m()` returns `void`, so you cannot assign it to `t`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the methods of the anonymous class using normal java, but you are able using reflection:

```
Test t = new Test{
    public void m() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to my class");
    }
};
Class<?> c = t.getClass();
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("m");
// m.setaccessible(true); // if private
m.invoke(t);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test t = new Test()
        {
            public void m() // this one will be called  
            {
                Runnable r = new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        m();
                    }
                };

                Test t = new Test()
                {
                    public void m()
                    {
                        r.run();
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }

    public void m()
    {

    }
}
```

If the method returns a value, use [`Callable<V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) instead.

Comment: This is not calling the enclosing class... It's just the same as doing `this.m()` from within `m()`.

Comment: IT IS calling the most enclosing class's instance method.

Comment: Can you mark which `m()` method will be called in the code? I am saying it will just call the `m()` method which has the `r.run()` statement in it... Which can be achieved by just putting `this.m()` instead of `r.run()`.

Comment: @Codebender Updated my answer.

Comment: But unfortunately it's wrong... You can make a quick test and you will see it's calling the innermost `m()` and throws up a SO error...

Comment: @Codebender Updated my answer.